# Can I assign a value to an iterator?

Tags: c++, vector, visual-studio-2013, stl, iterator

I'm working on a bit of code [here.](http://pastebin.com/yTbGBXc3)

Brief run-down, it's a text-based adventure, and when a player drops an item from their inventory, which is a `vector<_invent>` (`_invent` is a structure declared previously), the code fails at the line

```
*tempi = player_data.inventory[i];
```

and the error is "vector iterator not dereferencable"

I know an iterator is a fancy pointer. My question is should I assign the address of `inventory[i]` to `tempi`? Or should I assign the value of `inventory[i]` to the object that `tempi` points to?

Comment: `tempi = player_data.inventory.begin() + i;`

Comment: How did you come by this iterator? Might it be a constant iterator? Can you please show some example code, like a  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Also, please edit your question to include the *complete* and *unedited* error log, there might be other messages in it that gives some hints.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg >>>[link](http://pastebin.com/yTbGBXc3)<<< to the code example I pasted directly from the program I'm working on.

Comment: @Brian I feel so dumb. Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using

```
tempi = player_data.inventory.begin()
std::advance( tempi , i );
```

In case of `player_data.inventory` is `std::vector`,

Simply,

```
tempi = player_data.inventory.begin() + i;
```